# Jquery maximum call stack when run submit in submit handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit, form-submit

So, i got error when submit form with jquery "in" submit handler
like this

```
$('form#form').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).submit();
});
```

But i got error

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

it says it stop on $(this).submit()

this my full code

```
$('form#form').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let gambarTersisa = [];
      let gambarNodes = document.querySelectorAll('span[contenteditable] img, figure[contenteditable] img');
      for (let index = 0; index < gambarNodes.length; index++) {
        gambarTersisa[index] = gambarNodes[index].src;
      }
      $(this).append($("<input>")
        .attr('type', 'hidden')
        .attr('name', 'gambar')
        .attr("value", gambarTersisa)
      );
      $(this).submit();
    });
```

Comment: `$(this).submit();` -> `this.submit();` when inside a jquery submit handler to submit

Answer (score 0):

The result indicates jQuery calls submit event handlers added using jQuery when `$(this).submit()` is called. This infinite recursion is detected and reported as running out of stack space.

This differ from vanilla JavaScript where calling `form.submit` in a submit handler does not call the handler again.

A solution would be to not call `$(this).submit()` unconditionally - there must be a way to either let the submit happen (after not calling `e.preventDefault`) or not calling `$(this).submit()` to stay on the page.

Comment: So i should use vanilla javascript to submit ?

Comment: You could certainly try. But if you only don't want to submit under some circumstances, don't call ` e.preventDefault();` until you detect the submission should not occur. Like that, no second call to submit should be needed.

Answer (score 0):

NVM, sry i kinda dumb. so i just had to remove `prefentDefault` and return true.

This my finest code:

```
$('form#form').submit(function(e) {
  let gambarTersisa = [];
  let gambarNodes = document.querySelectorAll('span[contenteditable] img, figure[contenteditable] img');
  for (let index = 0; index < gambarNodes.length; index++) {
    gambarTersisa[index] = gambarNodes[index].src;
  }
  $(this).append(
    $("<input>")
      .attr('type', 'hidden')
      .attr('name', 'gambar')
      .attr("value", gambarTersisa)
  );
  return true;
});
```

Thanks anyway